# Laravel - FatalErrorException in View

Tags: laravel

FatalErrorException in 817ce6c1c88b960f15a24e1860c01690 line 95: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('

```
@foreach($home_programs as $data)
  <div class="row program-highlight-detail" id="highlight-content-{{$data->id}}" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-5 vertical-bottom">
      <img src="{{$data->image1}}" width="100%"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 vertical-bottom">
      <div class="program-highlight-detail-header">
        <p class="program-highlight-detail-title">{{$data->title}}</p>
        <p class="program-highlight-detail-description" style="text-align: justify;">{!!$data->content!!}</p>
        @if ($data->title == "UNDERGRADUATE PROGRAM")
          <a href="{{url('academic/bachelor-of-business-administration/introduction')}}" class="program-highlight-detail-link">LEARN MORE</a>
        @elseif ($data->title == "EXECUTIVE EDUCATION")
          <a href="{{url('executive-education/cma-prepatory-program-introduction')}}" class="program-highlight-detail-link">LEARN MORE</a>
        @elseif
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="{{$data->image2}}" width="100%"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="{{$data->image3}}" width="100%"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ending to your `@if` statement

Please replace `@elseif` to `@endif` after this line

```
<a href="{{url('executive-education/cma-prepatory-program-introduction')}}" class="program-highlight-detail-link">LEARN MORE</a>
```

Hope that fixes the issue :)